# VS2010 could not load VSTA project system package

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsta

When I try to open one particular project I get messages that VSTA project system package could not be loaded . I've enabled logging of VS2010 and discovered that this package can't be loaded because some files can not be found. I've done some searching over the internet and found out that VSTA is part of MS Office, and that there seems to be no separate installation distributive of VSTA. MS Office installation seems to include VSTA. My VS2010 is Professional edition and it has SP1 applied. What steps can I make to fix this error except reinstalling everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reinstalled VS2010 SP1 and it fixed my problem.